# Primefaces retrieve DataList or DataGrid value

Tags: primefaces

I have the below dataList that displays images with pagination that shows one image at a time.  I want to be able to know/retrieve what image is being displayed when I click my p:commandButton so that I can have access to it in my actionListener method (bookmarkletBean.update).  Any ideas here?

```
  <p:dataList value="#{bookmarkletBean.imageURLs}" var="img"  
                    paginator="true" rows="1" effectSpeed="fast" pageLinks="4"
                     paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" paginatorPosition="bottom">  
                    <p:column>  
                        <p:graphicImage value="#{img}" width="200" height="110"/> 
                    </p:column>  
                </p:dataList>  

<p:commandButton styleClass="form-btn1" value="#{bundle['save.button.TEXT']}"   
                        actionListener="#{bookmarkletBean.update}"  oncomplete="bookmarkletAddedDlg.show()" />
```

Comment: Well apparently formatting the post for easier and enhanced reading is not worth anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one possible solution was the below to arrange it like so with a link to select the wanted image and then the actionListener process's the selection

```
 <p:dataTable value="#{bookmarkletBean.imageURLs}" var="img"
              paginator="true" rows="1" effectSpeed="fast" pageLinks="4"
              paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" 
              paginatorPosition="bottom">  
              <p:column>  
                    <p:graphicImage value="#{img}" width="200" height="110"/> 
                        <p:commandLink> 
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{img}" target="#{bookmarkletBean.selectedImage}"/>
                                select image
                        </p:commandLink>
              </p:column>  
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Possible as both `p:dataList` and `p:dataGrid` dont have a *selection* property that can be attached to the backing bean your `p:commandButton` will belong to.

Therefore, I would recommend having a `p:dataTable` which does have the *selection* property, and once you click the button you will now which row (Image) was selected.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bookmarkletBean.imageURLs}" var="img" 
             selection"#{bookmarkletBean.selectedImage}"
             paginator="true" rows="1" effectSpeed="fast" pageLinks="4"
             paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks}     {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" paginatorPosition="bottom">  
                    <p:column>  
                        <p:graphicImage value="#{img}" width="200" height="110"/> 
                    </p:column>  
</p:dataTable>  

<p:commandButton styleClass="form-btn1" value="#{bundle['save.button.TEXT']}"   
                        actionListener="#{bookmarkletBean.update}"  oncomplete="bookmarkletAddedDlg.show()" />
```

Comment: thanks for the response and the help.  The selection didn't map the current row to my bean.  I think the selection property is meant to be used when there is a selection event (click, double click..etc).  I'm just using the pagination to go to the next image in the Collection.  The only way I get it to work is how I outlined in my the below post.  Any ideas?  Sorry about the previous formatting.